# Can I/ How do I use a static method in a non static environment

Tags: java, class, methods, static

```
public class Transcript {
    private List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();
    private int id;

    public void assignVariables(){
        for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
            if(grades.get(i).getLetter() == null){
                grades.get(i).setLetter(GPA2Letter(grades.get(i).gradePoint()));

            }
        }
    }

    public class Registrar {

    static double gpa;

    public Registrar(){

    }

    public static double letter2Point(String gradeIn){
        if(gradeIn == "A" ){
            gpa = 4.0;
        }
        else if(gradeIn == "B"){
            gpa = 3.0;
        }
        else if(gradeIn == "C"){
            gpa = 2.0;
        }
        else if(gradeIn == "D"){
            gpa = 1.0;
        }
        else if(gradeIn == "F"){
            gpa = 0;
        }
        return gpa;
    }

    public static String GPA2Letter(double gradePointIn){
        String letter = "";
        if(gradePointIn >= 4){
            letter = "A";
        }
        else if((gradePointIn >= 3) && (gradePointIn < 4)){
            letter = "B";
        }
        else if((gradePointIn >= 2) && (gradePointIn < 3)){
            letter = "C";
        }
        else if((gradePointIn >= 1) && (gradePointIn < 2)){
            letter = "D";
        }
        else if((gradePointIn >= 0) && (gradePointIn < 1)){
            letter = "F";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the GPA2Letter() method to process information in another class i was wondering how do I access this method or if I even can  note the class that I am doing this block of code in is not a static environment

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is, to be honest. It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You can always call static methods from anywhere. The thing that usually gets people in trouble is going the other way (e.g. trying to call a normal method from `main()` without having first created an object to call it on).  Please show us the code where you are trying to do this, and the full error message you are getting.

Comment: Note: `GPA2Letter` is not a good name for a method. According to the coding conventions, all methods should start with a lowercase letter, and it's recommended that they start with a verb, like `convertGPAToLetter`.

Comment: I gave more code right now it says it cannot access GPA2Letter() as a method @JonSkeet

Comment: You have to give it the context of the method.  e.g. Registrar.GPA2Letter()

Comment: GPA2Letter is in a different class Registrar

Comment: @Thorx99: Yes, exactly - so you specify the class and then the method, i.e. `Registrar.GPA2Letter`. You should also look at Java naming conventions, not using static variables when you don't need to, and the right way of comparing strings in Java...

Comment: @JonSkeet will do and thank you, yeah things got messy with this assignment.

Comment: Also, it seems like each `Transcript` should have its own `gpa`, no?